# Fsck on encrypted home folder, do I need to decrypt first?

Tags: fsck

I would like to run btrfs check on /dev/sda3 partition that have encrypted home folder. If I decrypt folder that partition became mounted. The check requires it be unmounted, thus encrypted. Is it safe to run `check --repair` in that case?

Comment: What method was used to encrypt the home folder?

Comment: Ubuntu cryptsetup